# Delete UITableView cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ipad

I am creating a small ipad application using the `UISplitViewController` which has a `UIMasterViewController` and a `UIDetailViewController`. I have removed the `UITableView` the comes with the `UIMasterViewController` and I have created my own `UITableView` by dragging and dropping one from the Xcode Objects panel. I have maned to populate the `UITableView` with data successfully however when i try to delete a cell or record from it I seem to get an "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error.

Below is my edit button code. (Which is a custom button):

```
//Edit Button
int cnt = 0;
- (IBAction)buttonEditPressed:(id)sender {

    if (cnt == 0){
    [self.myTableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    _buttonEdit.title = @"Done";
        cnt++;
    }
    else if (cnt == 1){
        [self.myTableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        _buttonEdit.title = @"Edit";
        cnt--;
    }

}
```

And the following code is where the deleting should happen (But gives me the erros instead):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

        [self.moduleTitleStack removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [self.myTableView reloadData];

}
```

[UPDATE] numberOfRowsInSection implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    //return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    return [_numberOfRows count];
}
```

I would think that this would do the job but not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: also, can you add your `numberOfRowsInSection:` implementation?

Comment: @Ismael the error is not very clear it just says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (See update for numberOfRowsInSection:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer:

You don't need to do `[tableView reloadData];` if you just deleted the row and nothing else changed.

Also, the crash you are getting, is that you are deleting an object from your `self.moduleTitleStack`, but the row count is checking for `_numberOfRows`. (I'm guessing they are different arrays), and that's the problem you are getting. You need to update the `_numberOfRows` to reflect the new setup of your table view

A general tip to know more about the exceptions you are getting:

Go to the breakpoints panel on the left, and on the lower left, click `Add` > `Exception Breakpoint` and then just hit OK. The debugger will stop whenever an exception is thrown, giving you some info about the exception, as well as the exact stack trace of where and how it happened